# i am trying to covert my expo app into an apk file but i get this error called android build failed see logs for more information

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

i am trying to covert my expo app into an apk file but i get this error called android build failed see logs for more information when i see  the build details the error is cased while installin gthe dependencies here is the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozrS0.jpg

and i dont know what it means by log

i am using eas

i tried creting a new expo project and copiying the code efiles into that project etc but nothing has worked and i have also tried to change the app name from RToDo to YOULIST I also think that is causing the issue

if you need any code files like (eas.json, app,json, etc) i can give it to you

Comment: your app has obviously problems with dependencies

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: see what stands in "install dependencies" log

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: i have put the image in the description